# How are the fs/gs registers used in Linux AMD64?

Tags: linux, assembly, architecture, x86, x86-64

On the x86-64 architecture, two registers have a special purpose: FS and GS. In linux 2.6.*, the FS register seem to be used to store thread-local information.

- Is that correct?
- What is stored at fs:0? Is there any C structure that describe this content?
- What is then the use of GS?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In x86-64 there are [3 TLS entries](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.39/source/arch/x86/include/asm/segment.h#L170), two of them accesible via [FS and GS](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.39/source/arch/x86/include/asm/segment.h#L176), FS is used internally by glibc (in IA32 apparently [FS is used by Wine and GS by glibc](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.39/source/arch/x86/include/asm/segment.h#L40)).

Glibc makes its TLS entry point to a [`struct pthread`](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/nptl/descr.h?v=GLIBC27;im=excerpts#L124) that contains some internal structures for threading. Glibc usually refers to a `struct pthread` variable as `pd`, presumably for *pthread descriptor*.

On x86-64, `struct pthread` starts with a [`tcbhead_t`](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/nptl/sysdeps/x86_64/tls.h?v=GLIBC27;im=excerpts#L45) (this depends on the architecture, see the macros [`TLS_DTV_AT_TP`](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/ident?v=GLIBC27;im=excerpts;i=TLS_DTV_AT_TP) and [`TLS_TCB_AT_TP`](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/ident?v=GLIBC27;im=excerpts;i=TLS_TCB_AT_TP)). This Thread Control Block Header, AFAIU, contains some fields that are needed even when there is a single thread. The DTV is the Dynamic Thread Vector, and contains pointers to TLS blocks for DSOs loaded via `dlopen()`. Before or after the TCB there is a static TLS block for the executable and DSOs linked at (program's) load time. The TCB and DTV are explained pretty well in [Ulrich Drepper's TLS document](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/tls.pdf) (look for the diagrams in chapter 3).

Comment: FS is used by win32 on x86 to point at the windows thread info -- wine is just matching that.

Comment: `TLS_DTV_AT_TP` is what Drepper's document (p. 5-6, 8) calls "Variant I", which he notes was invented for IA-64 (Itanium); `TLS_TCB_AT_TP` is what he calls "Variant II". In "Variant I", the DTV pointer is always at TCB offset 0, and the compiler is allowed to assume that; in "Variant II", it can be at an arbitrary offset, which the compiler can't know, so the compiler must rely on the runtime library `__tls_get_addr` function. On Linux, all new architectures use Variant I, Variant II is used by older architectures (x86_64, i386, s390, s390x and SPARC) due to backward compatibility.

Answer (score 25):

To actually answer your `fs:0` question: The x86_64 ABI requires that `fs:0` contains the address "pointed to" by `fs` itself. That is, `fs:-4` loads the value stored at `fs:0 - 4`. This feature is necessary because you cannot easily get the address pointed to by `fs` without going through kernel code. Having the address stored at `fs:0` thus makes working with thread local storage much more efficient.

You can see this in action when you take the address of a thread local variable:

```
static __thread int test = 0;

int *f(void) {
    return &test;
}

int g(void) {
    return test;
}
```

compiles to

```
f:
    movq    %fs:0, %rax
    leaq    -4(%rax), %rax
    retq

g:
    movl    %fs:-4, %eax
    retq
```

i686 does the same but with `%gs`. On aarch64 this is not necessary because the address can be read from the tls register itself.

Comment: Can you please privide source for "The x86_64 ABI requires that fs:0 contains the address "pointed to" by fs itself" ?

Comment: Apparently this is in the document "[ELF Handling for Thread-Local Storage](https://akkadia.org/drepper/tls.pdf)" which the ABI references.  `%fs:0` is described for two different models in sections 4.3.6 and 4.4.6.

Answer (score 7):

What is then the use of GS?

x86_64 Linux kernel uses GS register as a efficiency way to acquire kernel space stack for system calls.

GS register stores the base address for per-cpu area. To acquire the kernel space stack, in entry_SYSCALL_64

```
movq    PER_CPU_VAR(cpu_current_top_of_stack), %rsp
```

After expanding PER_CPU_VAR, we get the following:

```
movq    %gs:cpu_current_top_of_stack, %rsp
```

Comment: It does this after `swapgs`, of course, to set the gs segment base to the *kernel's* GS value, not user-space's value.  On entry from user-space, `%gs` is still whatever user-space set it to!  (`swapgs` and `syscall` were designed by AMD to be used together like this.)