# Debugging with segment register FS

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, x86, x86-64

I need to debug an application written in C that reads and writes to segment register FS. To debug this application I need to see the memory address where FS points to.

The application uses code like this:

```
mov rdx, fs:[rcx]
mov fs:[rcx], rsi
```

How do I get the linear virtual address of a read/write from/to segment registers? I can compile this application for either Linux or Winodws.

Comment: Windows uses FS for "per thread" variables, and the few times I've looked at the assembly code, it's converting FS:[...] into a regular virtual address. The current seed for rand() is one of those "per thread" variables, which is what I looked at.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611346/how-are-the-fs-gs-registers-used-in-linux-amd64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On linux, you can use `arch_prctl(ARCH_GET_FS, &fsbase)`. In windows, if the `FS` is pointing to the TEB as usual, you can read `fs:[0x18]` to get the base address, or use features of your debugger if available.