# To what data structure does FS register point to on Linux x86_64

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, thread-local-storage

To what data structure does FS register point to on Linux x86_64?
I heard that this segment register is used to implement thread local storage. However I can't find any resources to what data structure it actually points to. I need the data structure for user mode, if this makes a difference.

Thanks

Comment: So according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611346/how-are-the-fs-gs-registers-used-in-linux-amd64 , FS points to struct tcbhead_t (depending on macros). Is that correct?

Comment: @user2600312 Looks like it. Notice that there is also data *after* this structure.