# What is the GS register used for on Windows?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86

I've found MSDN documentation on the purpose of the FS register:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253960(v=vs.90).aspx

which states that:

> "In an x86 environment, the FS register points to the current value of
>   the Thread Information Block (TIB) structure."

But I cannot seem to find any rigorous documentation of the purpose of the GS register in a Windows based environment.

Can someone tell me where to look, or give an explanation?

Comment: Pretty much the same thing. See e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611346/how-are-the-fs-gs-registers-used-in-linux-amd64) and [this](https://github.com/wishstudio/flinux/wiki/Difference-between-Linux-and-Windows).

Comment: @Michael: I looked, but I don't see an answer to this question in either of them.  So Windows uses `FS` for the TIB, but what about `GS`?  Does it hold anything useful for user-space?  A quick google found that [`GS` holds the TIB reference on x86-64 Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block), which seems odd since `swapgs` makes it less convenient for the kernel to modify the user-space value of `gs`.  (Linux uses `fs` for TLS for this reason, IIRC).  But anyway, then the question is, what's the other segment register used for on 64-bit Windows?

Comment: The usage of FS and GS on Windows is an implementation detail and intentionally undocumented. If I remember correctly, reverse engineering suggests that on 32-bit Windows, FS holds a pointer to the TIB/TEB while GS either holds a pointer to thread-local storage (TLS) or is not used at all. On 64-bit Windows, GS points to the TIB/TEB. Why do you need to know this information? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 18):

On 32 bit Windows `GS` is reserved for future use.
The `FS` segment points to the [Thread information block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block).

In x64 mode the `FS` and `GS` segment registers have been swapped around.

In x86 mode `FS:[0]` points to the start of the [TIB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block), in X64 it's `GS:[0]`.
The reason Win64 uses `GS` is that there the `FS` register is used in the 32 bit compatibility layer (confusingly called Wow64).
Because 32-bit apps use `FS` the bookkeeping for Win64 is simplified.
32 bit applications never cause `GS` to be altered and 64 bit applications never cause `FS` to be altered.

Note that the fact that `GS` is non-zero in Win64 and Wow64 can be used to detect if a 32-bit application is running in 64-bit Windows.
In a 'true' 32 bit Windows `GS` is always zero.