# where is segment selector stored for context switching. (x86)

Tags: x86, operating-system, cpu, memory-segmentation

From what I've read, on modern OS including windows and linux, segment registers such as CS, DS, etc are not used. My questions are:

1. If that's the case, where is segment selector stored?
2. Does each thread has its own segment selector?

Answer (score 3):

What you read was over-simplified.

Segment registers have to be used to make the CPU work in protected / long mode, they just aren't used for anything *interesting*.  (Except for [FS or GS being used for thread-local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611346/how-are-the-fs-gs-registers-used-in-linux-amd64/33827186)).  Modern OSes use a flat memory model where all segments have base=0 and limit=4GiB (and in 64-bit mode, the HW ignores base and limit, except for FS/GS).

The code-segment descriptor selected by CS determines whether the process runs in long mode or compat mode, under a 64-bit kernel.  (The L bit in the descriptor).  See http://wiki.osdev.org/GDT.

All 32-bit processes use the same CS value, while all 64-bit processes use the same CS value (but different from 32-bit processes).  Modern OSes don't always save/restore all segment registers, e.g. on returning to user mode after a system call, some of Linux's return paths use a constant `__USER32_CS` or `__USER_CS`.  There's also a `__USER_DS` constant that's used to initialize DS and ES so they select a descriptor that works.  (See some links and comments on the system-call return path in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code/46087731#46087731).)

Comment: Modern OSes use flat memory model. So how does protection work between user and kernel mode? Could you elaborate? thanks

Comment: @c.critter [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), where the OS manages the [page tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table).  User-space can only read/write the pages the OS maps into its virtual address space.