# `fs` relative address in x86-64

Tags: assembly, x86-64, abi, bare-metal, thread-local-storage

I am trying to use thread local storage in Rust on bare bones. I initially set the `FsBase` MSR to the target value. This is also confirmed by reading the `FsBase` register again and by running `info registers fs_base` in gdb.

When I try to read a thread local variable, rust generates the following asm code (disassembly from gdb)

```
mov    %fs:0x0,%rax
mov    -0x2000(%rax),%cl
mov    %cl,-0x189(%rbp)
```

When i try to step through these instructions, I observe that after instruction 1, the value of `%rax` stays as 0x0 rather than using the value in `FsBase`. This is not expected behavior.

In my case, the FsBase is set to `0xffffc00000002000`. After running into instruction 3, the cpu raises a page fault exception with the target location being `0xffffffffffffe000` meaning that the instruction is trying to load data from `0x0 - 0x2000` rather than an offset from `0xffffc00000002000`. This is not the expected behavior.

Are there more steps required to instantiate `fs` registers?

Comment: `mov    %fs:0x0,%rax` is a load (from thread-local storage, which later gets used as a pointer).  If RAX = 0 afterwards, the qword in memory at `FsBase` was zero.  Did you expect something else?

Comment: Yes, my `FsBase` is no non-zero high memory value. (`0xffffc00000002000`)

Comment: But `mov` is a load from memory at that address, not `rdfsbase %rax`.  There's one extra level of indirection you don't seem to be accounting for.

Comment: This is the compiler generated code for accessing thread local storage. I made sure i did not skip any more instructions to load the data.

Comment: The compiler is assuming that operating system and/or runtime environment has setup thread local storage in a particular way.  It's assuming that a pointer to the thread local storage is located at `%fs:0`, but you have the value 0 there instead. The compiler may also be assuming other things not shown by fragment of generated code you've shown.  It's not sufficient for you to simply set FS.Base to some value.

Comment: Based on the code sequence generated it's likely your compiler is using the TLS extensions to the System V ABI defined in the document titled "ELF Handling for Thread-Local Storage".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code generation here is according to System V ABI as Ross mentioned in the comment.
The ABI requires `%fs:0` to be set to the value of `%fs` [itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33827186/2178906).

So, here, setting the value at address `0xffffc00000002000` to be `0xffffc00000002000` satisfies the ABI and uses the FsBase as expected.

In other words, `mov %fs:0x0, %rax` is trying to access the value at `FsBase` and not at `0x0`. The value at FsBase just happens to be 0.

Comment: Note that this makes sense for performance reasons. For most CPUs, an "`fs` segment override prefix"  has a performance cost; so if you want to access thread local variables  many times (e.g. in a loop) then it can be faster to convert to a normal address that doesn't use `fs` and use that instead (e.g. load `%fs:0` into a normal register and use `reg+offset` instead of  `%fs:offset`).